# Getting error with dots in the url

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, url-routing

I have a routed page with url like http://www.example.com/2/2332/example
Now when i give a period in the url http://www.example.com/2/2332/example. I am taken to the server error page:

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

I would like to redirect to the same page http://www.example.com/2/2332/example or my custom 404 error page http://www.example.com/404.aspx.

I tried debugging but its not hitting the Application_Error event in the Global.asax.cs.

Any help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The breakpoint is not hit because it is not an asp.net error. It is an IIS error. You have to [modify web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2012/01/15/custom-error-pages-and-404-page-not-found-error-web-config-setup.aspx) to redirect to a custom error page.

Comment: The web.config is already modified for custom error page, I am redirecting to the error page with any other urls but not being redirected for this case.

Comment: Try relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx

Comment: relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping  thanks rocky this worked out for me... :)